# How to make a java application's external jars usable to it's plug ins

Tags: java

I want to make a java application that supports plug ins. Now my core will use jars for certain processes. If my plug ins where to also use these jars, do the plug ins of my application need to configure their build path to include the jars they would also use or is their a way so that the jars can be imported similar to how I import packages from the main application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guice and Spring are tools for dependency injection, which means that creating objects is easier with them because they take care of instantiating objects and placing them into other objects that depends on them.

Now, when we talk about plugins, we usually are talking too about dynamically loading new classes into a running app. Think on eclipse IDE. Its architecture was designed from the beginning to be "pluggable", like, you can download jars and eclipse will add them to the running application without the need of application restart.

In this case, if you want to build pluggable apps, in a sense of dynamic classloading, I'd recommend you not to go through this path, but to research subjects such as OSGI. One popular OSGI framework is http://felix.apache.org/

Another approach for application extension (we may call this pluggable too, somehow, I guess), depending on how your app is organized and what it does, is to develop a DSL (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) for it and extend it letting people adding scripts to it. Isn't something like this when a browser let you add pieces of funcionality written in javascript? Groovy makes DSL easier in some aspects, for java programmers. (see http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Writing+Domain-Specific+Languages)

Comment: I am terribly sorry for the misunderstanding. I did not mean I would be using guice jar to dynamically load plug ins. I stated that my application will use guice for dependency handling. It was just an example. I have updated my question for clarity. My real problem is how my plug ins will cleanly use jars that were used by my main application

Comment: no problem. still, for dealing with dynamic jar loading, I think the way is OSGI, as I've stated in the answer. :-)

Comment: OSGi is too much for what I need. I already read about it. Decided to stick with the Service Provider Interface. Although OSGi will surely be a more solid approach, this project is simply for fun thus I went with simplicity. I can solve my problem by adding the build path of external jars my plug ins used such as guice. I just feel it isnt clean.

Comment: if it's for fun, why don't you try learning something that you would't like to learn with a real project for profit? ;-) but if SPI is ok for you, have fun ;-)

Comment: Time constraint to set up the OSGi framework I suppose.

Comment: Sounds reasonable ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want dynamic plugable systems OSGI can give you this, but OSGI its IMMO a over-complicated technology, use only if you are really sure that needs this dynamic plug-ability.

Other option for builds extensible systems its use de ServiceProvider mechanism, this is a core java mechanism, for example its the one that JDBC implementations use, you can put a JDBC driver in your classpath and the application can find it and use it without needing that you explicitly import the driver classes in your code.

This is an example of using ServiceProvider in your owns applications: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/spi.html#limitations-of-the-service-loader-api

Its of course more limited than OSGI, but its very easy to use when you get the idea, and you don't need any external library because its a java core mechanism.

EDIT: about the libraries.

In runtime: With ServiceProvicer there is no separate classloaders (you can implement off course, but by default, in OSGI its implemented this separation), in runtime if your plugin need X class and this class is in the classpath all is ok, the limitation its that the main application and all the plugins use this version of the dependency (guice 3 for example) and you cannot have one plugin using X version and other plugin using X+2 version if this version are not compatible. (this is the famous hell .jar, and one of the principal motivations behind jigsaw project for example).

In compile time, include the dependency in your pom, ant build file, gradle build file or whatever build system your use as usual.